# How to play many wma files in a loop

Tags: delphi

How can I play 20 wma files on delphi using Tmediaplayer, one after another in a continues loop until the program is closed ? I already tried using a timer for each file , but I keep failing. I have 20 songs that I'd like to play in the background while the rest of the program runs.

Comment: Could you show your code please

Comment: Indeed, "keeps failing" isn't a valid diagnosis. Try taking a car to a mechanic and just telling them "it's failing" and see if the mechanic can fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the filenames into a list.  Set the `TMediaPlayer.FileName` property to the first filename in the list, set the `TMediaPlayer.Notify` property to true, and call `TMediaPlayer.Play()`.  When the `TMediaPlayer.OnNotify` event signals playback has finished, you can assign the next filename in the list to `TMediaPlayer.FileName`, reset `TMediaPlayer.Notify` to true, and call `TMediaPlayer.Play()`.  Repeat for each filename in the list.  One you have played the last filename, start over with the first filename.